# passing matrices in functions in python

Tags: python, list

I want pass a matrix to a function (as a parameter) but an error appeared said

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

here is my code

```
def question_1_b(arr):
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            block[4*i+j] = arr[i,j]
    return block

question_1_b([[70,52,13,67],[90,48,57,26],[43,45,67,89],[88,65,44,23]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address a nested list, use separate indices for the outer and inner lists:

```
block[4*i+j] = arr[i][j]
```

`i, j` forms a tuple (the comma makes it a tuple, not parenthesis).

You could just loop directly over the matrix lists, using the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to generate the indices for the `block` index calculation:

```
for i, outer in enumerate(arr):
    for j, value in enumerate(outer):
        block[4 * i + j] = value
```